# Compute the differential map of $\exp(sX): \mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^3$ where $X$ is an element of $\mathfrak s\mathfrak o(3)$

Tags: matrices, lie-groups, lie-algebras, rotations

Let $SO(3)$ be the rotation group of $\mathbb R^3$ and $\mathfrak s\mathfrak o(3)$ be its lie algebra of $3\times 3$ skew-symmetric matrices. Each element $A\in SO(3)$ acts in  $\mathbb R^3$ via:
$$v\mapsto A\cdot v$$
So given $X\in \mathfrak s\mathfrak o(3)$, the one-parameter subgroup $s\mapsto \exp(sX)$ of $X$ defines a group of transformations in $\mathbb R^3$:
$$\begin{array}{rcll}
g_s:&\mathbb R^3&\longrightarrow &\mathbb R^3\\
&v&\longmapsto & g_s(v)=\exp(sX)(v)
\end{array}$$
I am trying to compute the tangent lift $T(g_s):T(\mathbb R^3)\cong \mathbb R^3\times \mathbb R^3\to T(\mathbb R^3)$ but I am stuck. How can I compute the differential of $g_s$? More precisely:

**How can I compute the differential of $\exp(sX)$ as a rotation of $\mathbb R^3$?**

> *Note:* I am doing this in order to show that a Lagrangian in $\mathbb R^3$ that admits $\{g_s\}$ as symmetry group has the angular momentum as integral of motion (without using Noether's Theorem)

Comment: Recall that $\exp (sX) = I + sX + O(s^2)$.

Comment: Isn't $g_s$ just a linear mapping? So the derivative is more or less itself.